# Bind a reference to a non-reference object to a Form's Control in C#

Tags: c#, reference

I've created a data-driven way in my c# application to create UI elements that let me debug non-reference type variables (bools, ints, etc) at runtime for debugging purposes. Since, you can't store references in c# (like you could if you just passed a pointer in C++), as explained in [Storing a reference in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866400/storing-a-reference-in-c-sharp), I have to create delegates to get and set any variable I would like to debug as such:

```
createCheckboxSetting("Debug Bool",
                      delegate(bool newVal) { testBool = newVal; },
                      delegate() { return testBool; });
```

I would LOVE to not have to write this bubblegum code **every single time**, in order for the code-generated controls in my debugging form to update the variable passed in (via the Form Checkbox's Click event). Is there any way that I can get this to work so that I can call the function in the following manner instead (or something comparably simple)?

```
createCheckboxSetting("Debug Bool", ref testBool);
```

If I attempt to create the delegates within createCheckboxSetting, I get the following error:
"Cannot use ref or out parameter 'VARIABLE_NAME' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression." If there's a cleaner way to do this I really don't know how and I would really like to keep this quick and simple to use for obvious reasons.

I really appreciate the help, as I'm still trying to get used to C#. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say I understand your question completely, but if you wish to make your non-reference type "variables" (fields?) reference-able, you can put them inside of a class. For example, create a dictionary field mapping strings or integer constants to a FieldBase class, then store in that dictionary all the FieldBase objects you need, and look them up by name. The FieldBase class can be non-generic, and derived classes generic:

```
abstract class FieldBase
{
    public readonly string Name;
    protected FieldBase(string name) { Name = name; }
}
sealed class Field<T> : FieldBase where T : struct
{
    public Field(string name) : base(name) { }
    public T Value;
}
```

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the response! I was hoping to be able to leave a bool varialbe as is and just pass it into a function in such a way that its value can be changed by a checkbox directly. In C++ I would just pass a pointer to the variable into the function that creates the checkbox and have it update the dereferenced pointer when it changes.

Any suggestions as to what I should clear up in the question to make it more understandable would also be appreciated.

Comment: While we can pass a reference to a field to a function and manipulate it that way, we cannot hold onto that reference, as you would a pointer in C++. For example, SetField<T>(ref T field, T newValue) { field = newValue; }, works, but you cannot hold onto field in any way.