# C# - passing variable by reference to object doesn't modify original value?

Tags: c#, .net, reference

I have a program that runs so long as the `running` boolean is true. In this example below I try to pass the `running`  variable by reference to another object and modify it within the object(in the else block of `route_command`).

## Program class:

```
    class Program
    {
        public static bool running = true;
        public static AesManaged aes = new AesManaged();        //default encryption key
        public static Logger logger = new Logger();
        public static Checker checker = new Checker(ref aes , ref running);

     
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            logger.intro();
           
            while (running == true) {
                string command = Console.ReadLine();
                checker.route_command(command);



            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

## checker class :

```
public class Checker
    {   
        RijAlgo rij = new RijAlgo(); //encryption class
        AesManaged aes;
        bool running;
        public Checker(ref AesManaged aes_parent, ref bool running_parent)
            {
                aes = aes_parent;
                running = running_parent;

         }
        public void route_command(string command)
        {
            string[] command_params = command.Split(" ");
           
             if (command_params.Length < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please make sure you provide a second parameter");
            }
            else
            {
                running = false;
            }
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even when passed by reference, when you assign the parameter to something else, you're only assigning the _value_ of the parameter, not the reference.

Comment: think this answers my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866400/storing-a-reference-in-c-sharp

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Recent versions of C# support ["ref returns and ref locals"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns), and there _might_ be a way to refactor your design to take advantage of that. But IMHO you really should just provide a more OOP-wise way of signaling between the classes, per older guidance.

Comment: @PeterDuniho right now I guess I will just pass by ref to the command checker.